# Will users misunderstand "Last week", "Last year", "Last month" etc?

Tags: dates, wording

In my diary iOS app, the user can search their diaries for specific texts. To avoid getting too many results, I added a "Time Range" search option. The user can select whether to only search the diaries of the last 7 days, the last 30 days, the last 365 days or not to have a limit.

If I display these options in a `UISegmentedControl`, like this

```
| Lifetime | Last 365 days | Last 30 days | Last 7 days |
```

They won't be able to fit on some smaller iPhone screens and will become truncated:

```
| Lifetime | Last... | Last 30... | Last 7 da... |
```

So I want to shorten them so that it fits on every iPhone screen. I thought of using "Last XXX", like this:

```
| Lifetime | Last year | Last month | Last week |
```

And it barely fits.

When the user selects "Last week", it will actually search for diaries in the last 7 days (Jun 14-20), not Jun 12-18. So will users misunderstand this? If they will, how can I change it so that there are no misunderstandings and it can fit on the screen?

Comment: In germany we distinguish between this and last month. So if I wanna search in june, I use this month, if I want to search in may I use last month. And neither of both is like last 30 days form me.

Comment: I would be confused

Comment: "Will users misunderstand x" the answer is always yes, the real question is how many do and if you care about them.

Comment: If this was June (any date) I would expect "Last month" to be a search in (all of) May (and excluding June completely).

Comment: If something says it will show 'last month', people will expect the range to be the last calendar month not the last 30 days.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41541/discussion-on-question-by-sweeper-will-users-misunderstand-last-week-last-ye).

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I guess "previous" is a better translation than "last". "Last" seems kind of slang to me ("letzte Woche" ist eigentlich die "vorherige Woche" IMO).

Comment: There is a difference between "last 365 days" and "last year."  If today is June 25, 2016, then "last 365 days" means "from June 26, 2015 to June 25, 2016" where "last year" could mean "from January 1, 2015 to December 31, 2015" to some users.

Comment: @UweKeim you are right - or at least kind of. Depending on where one is, it is the one or the other. Whatever, it seems last/previous month is definitly NOT the last 30days for me, everything else I can "accept" ;-). Whatever, it is ambigious so a bad term :)

Comment: Is it visible from the result of the search what is meant? Then they will get used to it even if some might be confused at first.

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid each result will have a date associated with it. The user can select how the results are sorted: whether earlier results appear first or last, or whether to sort alphabetically. So I guess if the user wants to sort the results alphabetically, they might need a little deduction to figure this out.

Comment: @Sweeper For me it would not be confusing then but I am a technically advanced user. It probably depends on what kind of users you are targeting. So probably you should stick with the solution in the accepted answer. Have you checked how other apps are handling it?

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid I am targeting just normal users. The Google AdSense app seems to use "Last 30 days" in a dropdown menu. But I'm too lazy to implement such a thing, so I stuck with the accepted answer

Answer (score 125, accepted):

|**All**| or last | **365** | **30** | **7** | days

Comment: Could also be done with a dropdown for the number of days saving a little more space.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. But will people be confused if I use last month?

Comment: My thought is that, in a diary search app, people expect to see options that searches for last 7 days, last 30 days, etc. so I think people will see the last xxx options and think "Ah, I think it meant last xxx days". Am I right?

Comment: When I read the question, I had the same exact idea. I would just put some spaces around "*All*" and I would clarify that each day is a different button

Comment: Should you use 'last month' ? - no.  See my comment against the responses to the question.

Comment: @Sweeper: some people will misunderstand it, certainly. They will expect "last month" to mean "May", not "last 30 days", and "last week" to mean either Mon-Sun or Sun-Sat, not "last 7 days". Whether they'll be *confused* depends whether they can figure out what's really going on. Clicking something and discovering it doesn't do what you expected does not necessarily cause confusion, just surprise. But the phrase is ambiguous in English anyway (compare "did you go last month?" to "have you been in the last month?") so they have a chance of figuring it out.

Comment: Thus "Past 30 days" is less problematic. "Past month" is close to that.

Comment: perhaps `Show: | All | 365d | 30d | 7d |`?

Comment: 366 days and 31 days are more likely to include the full desired span of a year or month. I for one hate it when such intervals are badly approximated and not called by their common names.

Comment: You have another gold badge! Congratulations.

Answer (score 72):

Consider this:

`| Past year | Past month | Past week |`

This is much less likely to be misunderstood than "last year", and is a common way of presenting menus for selecting a time range.  For example, the filters for Google search and Reddit's top posts use this exact wording.

Comment: I don't think this answers the initial question, because you're using the same approach, just different terminology.

Comment: @MJB, different terminology **is** a different approach.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm sorry but I have to disagree. But even if it is a different approach, it still doesn't help solve the problem, a user can still see "past week" as either the last 7 days, or the actual last week (i.e. week 24 of the year).

Comment: @MJB I think it's much clearer though--definitely a step in the right direction. Even in your explanation of the ambiguity you claimed that you saw with "past week", you mentioned that a user would see that as "either the last 7 days, or the actual *last* week"...  you didn't say *past* week.. If someone asks "when did you go camping?" someone might respond "last month" but no one would respond "past month". "Last" is more ambiguous than "past".

Comment: This is potentially even worse. The past week doesn't include the current week. It is the week before the current week. 'Last week' may be more ambiguous in it meaning either the current or previous week, but it at least allows for days of the current week.

Comment: @PixelSnader While using the phrase "last week" can be ambiguous, "past week" (or "past month" or whatever) implies a "rolling" period.  Think of when a nurse asks questions at a hospital: "Have you traveled to a country outside the US in the past thirty days?" This is obviously a rolling 30 day period that ended today.  Asking the same question "...in the past month?" means the same thing, and is unambiguous (in writing, anyway).

Comment: @PixelSnader No, that is not how dictionaries define [past (see 1.2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/past), nor is it how Reddit and Google use the phrase.

Comment: Past week confuses me; last seven days, or previous week?? MS Outlook has this issue.

Comment: @flornquake [A] In that link, definition 1 "Gone by in time and no longer existing". The current month still exists. The month that is *past* (today being June 21st) is May. May is past. June is ongoing. [B] Just because Google does something doesn't mean it's right. For example category order (potato -> All | Images | Video | Shopping versus London -> All | Images | Maps | News) is inconsistent. Oh, and in Calendar the tags are just Day | Week | Month | 4 Weeks without any mention of 'past'.

Comment: @PixelSnader [A] If I told you "For the past month and a half, my roof has been leaking," would you think I'm talking about the past ~6 weeks, or would you honestly understand that to be a month and a half before the start of this current month? [B] Google's inconsistency here, I believe, has much more to do with which of their search products you're most likely to need. "All" is always first, then they assume *you're probably not looking for a map of a potato*, so they hide that product in their "More" dropdown. I find this inference rather helpful.

Comment: @flornquake I agreed, but a quick-n-dirty prototype and survey might put proof in the pudding here.

Comment: As a UK native english speaker, I would understand "Past" to be a rolling period from the time we're speaking and Last to be a previous "whole" period to the current "whole" period. Giving a number and then units bypasses that and makes both Past and Last mean the same. "Past month" is a bit wooly, but I would interpret it as the number of days back to the same date in the previous month, if it exists, or the past 28 to 31 days. So, "Last week" =/= "Past week", "Last 7 days" == "Past 7 days" == "Past week"

Answer (score 28):

Given today's date, 6/20/2016, I offer my users these choices:

```
Today          6/20/2016
Yesterday      6/19/2016
Last 7 Days    6/14/2016 - 6/20/2016
Last 30 Days   5/22/2016 - 6/20/2016
This Month     6/1/2016 - 6/20/2016
Last Month     5/1/2016 - 5/31/2016
This Year      1/1/2016 - 6/20/2016
Last Year      1/1/2015 - 12/31/2015
All Time       First Record - 6/20/2016
Custom Range   User uses calendar
```

[image]

Upon clicking one of the choices from the list, the black bar at the top will reflect the appropriate date range.

Comment: This is much better than MS Outlook, where you can find things last week, but not last 7 days; why on earth would I want to search all days last week, but not Monday etc., when it is Wednesday.

Comment: @MarkStewart Glad you like my implementation :). I agree, MS Outlook can certainly be screwy at times.

Comment: I'd take out the "(default)" bit. It's just noise/confusing when you don't have All Time selected, and when you first load the page presumably All Time _is_ clearly selected, so it's also redundant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll have to consider that, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this answer miss the point of the question? The OP said that they can't use "Last 7 days" because of the size of the control on the iphone.

Comment: @MarkStewart I had this exact thing happen today (though not in Outlook) where I had to show a month of data when 7 days would have sufficed, only, not *last* week excluding this one.

Comment: @Andrew hmm, you're right, lol. Whoops

Answer (score 19):

I would skip the 'Last' altogether and go with

`Lifetime | 1 year | 30 days | 7 days`

At most it would take the user one try to remember what it means, especially if you display the date range of the selected period once selected

Comment: Why would you not use `1 month` and `1 week`, but `1 year`?

Comment: @Crissov People are more accustomed to a rolling year, where all sorts of things are measured in years that don't necessarily start on January 1. But *week* and *month* seem to be conceived of as starting and ending on Sunday and the 1st, rather than referring to the most recent 7 or 30 days.

Comment: IBTD - weeks start on Monday :)

Comment: And, of course, not all ***months*** are 30 days long.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher No, weeks start on *Sunday, not Monday*.

Comment: US weeks start on Sunday. Some other places start on Monday. Because otherwise it would be too easy.

Comment: @Karen because god rested at the first day and then started to do stuff?

Comment: @Falco, no clue. I just know that if I'm working with people in other countries, it occasionally causes confusion. If you're curious, maybe try the history stack exchange?

Answer (score 7):

A screenshot from iOS Health app:

No `past` or `last`. Simple. Understandable. Fit for smaller screens.

[image]

Comment: It is not immideately obvious to me whether "week" means the last seven days, or every day since the last Sunday, or every day since the last Monday.

Comment: that's true - and I think that's why we are debating this question here, it's difficult to convey the information concisely - but in my opinion, that's all you get on a phone screen. It's true that a lot of people use iPhone 6+, but many apps still need to support iPhone 4s. I think it's totally fine for people to click into "Week" or "Month", and over there, you can detail the exact meaning of it, whether it's last seven days, or whatever.

Comment: What Flimm said is true. -1

Answer (score 5):

[image: **ERROR 404 MOCKUP NOT FOUND**]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWh9Ae.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The dropdown menu is a better idea, and it fits on most screens.

Also, you *should* include a "custom" option. You can't imagine how many people are **FRUSTRATED** everyday because **THERE IS NO CUSTOM OPTION!**

That said, the mockup is an example of a diary app with the dropdown menu.

Comment: There would be no need to attempt imagining if you provided _data_ ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is an example of a diary app. It saves daily diary notes, and you are able to access them by choosing a calendar date or writing it in the date area above the calendar selector. You can also search for notes with a specific content. The part to focus more is the drop-down at the top-left area. Yep, it is password-protected. No need to put data.

Comment: What I meant is that you said lots of people are frustrated every day that there is no custom option, but did not provide any indication of _how many_ people are frustrated, nor any evidence to back up the claim :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is on purpose; it just indicates *I* am frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

It might be confusing at first, but the disambiguation comes quickly:

- Showing data for the month before the current one exclusively is silly. No one would consider such a feature.
- As soon as you click on it, you'll see what appears. You may also add the indication of the precise time range somewhere (with actual dates) after the user selects one option.

So the user may be confused for a short time, but understand how it works pretty quickly.

Comment: I agree that people could figure it out, but ideally we would be able to design it in such a way that it's immediately obvious and the user doesn't have to put forth any conscious effort to process the UI. I think we could do better than just betting that "the user will be able to figure it out". They shouldn't have to try.

Comment: the overall meaning is immediate: filter based on a given period, with an indication of the duration of the filter. The specifics are necessarily confusing, as the wording is fuzzy. I remember very long conversations regarding the meaning of "next friday", depending on what the current day is (not in english, though).

Comment: Counterpoint: I've seen software where the data shown has been exclusively the month before the current one. It's more common in internal corporate software because it's super easy to do and is valid for establishing monthly trends. Certain users would definitely have trouble parsing it. As for the second point, you should never rely on exploration. Not all users are going to want to figure out things on their own and they shouldn't have to.

Comment: @RyNo your first point is very valid (but in that case, either the user knows the context and the feature should behave as you describe, or it should not). However, I disagree on exploration. User sees a button, understands a meaning, tries to use it for what they think it does, verifies or modified their understanding of the feature.

Comment: @njzk2 I agree with that in certain contexts (I prefer learning by exploration myself), but that can be a dangerous generalization. First, learning by exploration is something people with strong technical skills take for granted. It is a skill, and like all skills, for most it must be developed over time. Most features should be as accessible as possible. Second, sometimes a feature like this might be in a sensitive production environment. When exploration could possibly lead to data loss, you need to make things as clear as possible so your users are less likely to make a costly mistake.

Comment: I've used software (eg. my bank's account-activity listing) that interprets "last month" as the most recent complete month, and "last week" as the previous Sunday-to-Saturday period.  Maybe you consider "the month before the current one" as silly, but it's hardly a universal sentiment.

Comment: @Mark context is key, here. compare bank activity and e.g. email filtering

Comment: The point is, software does the damnedest things, and users have peculiar expectations of what software is going to do. If it's Tuesday, and the user does a search for "Last Week", and the system displays results for the preceding Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday, the user's preconceptions of the system's design are not challenged (unless she happens to know that there were things that should have been displayed, but weren't).

Comment: @Scott if your definition of last week when it is tuesday is the last wednesday, thursday, friday, then we have a different understanding of it. (And a different meaning to "week")

Comment: @njzk2: OK, I see that I wasn't clear.  If you search your diary for "Band practice" or "Lunch with Fred", you're not guaranteed to get at least one hit from each day of any given week.  If you had lunch with Fred on Monday (eight days ago), Wednesday (six days ago), and Friday (four days ago), and you're searching your diary for it, that suggests that you don't clearly remember the dates.  And, if the system searches (today−7) through (today) and gives you results from Wednesday and Friday, you might not realize that it wasn't searching (today−9) through (today−3) — or vice versa.

Comment: @Scott good point. But the real difficulties comes when the definition chosen by the developer does not match the expectation of the user. I assume there will always be users expecting (today - 7) to today, and users expecting the previous full monday - sunday period (and of course those expecting it to be sunday - saturday), and those expecting the previous monday (sunday) until today. Some will be disappointed, I am not sure which group is the largest, but I think the best way to manage that is to have a clear indication of the filter period after the selection is made.

Comment: @Scott but nonetheless, I still find that removing items from the end of the list is pointless, since it is a list and the user starts at the top.

Answer (score 1):

## Be clear

Here's an example of this type of control from a business intel app I worked on. This is used like a semented control across the top of various reports and Dashboard widgets.

[image: Quick date range selector]

What you've described may fit your space, but it's semantically incorrect. If it's June and your date control is labeled `Last month`, that clearly means May.

What you're looking for is a way to communicate rolling dates. Expected terminology can change from one industry to the next. As with any facet of your app, you'll want to do some research into what users expect these labels to be.

## General terminology

Date modifiers

- **Prev [# of x]**
  "[# of x] before today"
- **Last [# of x]**
  "The last [# of x] including today"
- **Rolling [# of x]**
  Same as above
- **[Period] to date**
  "Days within the period up to today"

Answer (score 1):

On Tuesday, 21 June 2016:

```
Since: | birth | June 2015 | 20 May | Wednesday |
```

Here are my alternative suggestions:

```
Since: | 0 | Jun’15 | 20May | Wed |
From: | start | year ago | month ago | week ago |

Only: | Past | Past year | Past month | Past week |
Only: | Past | … year | … month | … week |
Only: | Any | A year | A month | A week |
Only: | All | 1 year | 1 month | 1 week |
```

In many scenarios, `this` or `present` may be used for Monday through today, 1st through today or 1 January through today.

`Previous year`, `previous month`, `previous week` would most likely mean 1 January through 31 December, 1st through last day of May, Monday through Sunday for most people.

You could also use a slider with two selectors for start and end, and indicators (or snap locations) for week, month or year boundaries as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Use "past year, past month, past week."
If you say "last year" and it was 2016, users assume you mean 2015. Using the word "past" implies that you mean rolling days, thus making it much more understandable.
The same thing applies for months and weeks.

Comment: What does this offer over the answer that said the same thing 4 days earlier?